# sql question - Select columns and show in different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, row

thanks to this forum, I have found many answers to my questions.
I have a sql question . Hope someone can help.
There is a table with 2 columns for simplicity sake. Unsorted.

| Numbers | Letters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 3 | S |
| 2 | L |

etc..
How can I select multiple coulmns and put in different rows?
FOr ex- output should be as an added column

| Newcol |
| --- |
| 1 |
| A |
| C |
| 2 |
| B |
| L |
| 3 |
| S |

I tried Lag, Lead , CTE etc...I am unable to produce the desired results. any help is appreciated.
thanks

```
INSERT INTO T1 
  (numbers, letters)
  VALUES 
  ('1', '1A'),
  ('1', '1B'),
  ('1', '1C'),
  (3, '3B'),
  (1, '3C'),
  (3, '3D'),
  (2, '2A'),
  (4, '2B'),
  (7, '2C'),
  (3, '3A')
  ;
```

```
;
with cte as (select top(1000000) numbers, letters
             from T1
             order by numbers)

select numbers, letters as newcol
from cte order by cte.numbers,  cte.letters;
```

i need ordered by first column - then second column. is it possible? Any help appreciated. thanks

Comment: Can you please format your data and desired output in better tabular format?

Comment: Hi. I have formatted it in tabular format. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Below code will resolve your problem:-

```
SELECT numbers, letters, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY numbers ORDER BY letters) as newcol
FROM T1
ORDER BY numbers, letters
```